# Error "Task :react-native-vision-camera:buildCMakeDebug FAILED"

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-vision-camera

I am trying to build React Native for Android with React Native vision camera and reanimated; however, I am getting this error.
"Task :react-native-vision-camera:buildCMakeDebug FAILED" , and I think it is related to reanimated.

I am using the following:

React Native: 0.68.2
Reanimated: ^2.11.0
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.14.1"
"vision-camera-code-scanner": "^0.2.0"